# Detect if a device (printer, scanner, mouse, etc...) isn't working

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, delphi-xe2

If a printer has a problem, Windows's Device manager shows a special icon next to the printer in question.

I'm using Delphi XE2 and I'd like to know how to programmatically detect such info for Windows XP or later, ie.

```
function DetectDriversProblems() : TStringList;
begin
    // Scan Computer or query Windows to know if a driver has issues and
    // return list of faulty hardware (if any)
end;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use the [`Win32_PnPEntity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394353%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) WMI class and `ConfigManagerErrorCode` property.

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils,
  ActiveX,
  ComObj,
  Variants;

  Procedure ListDevicesConfigError;
    const
      wbemFlagForwardOnly = $00000020;
    var
      FSWbemLocator : OLEVariant;
      FWMIService   : OLEVariant;
      FWbemObjectSet: OLEVariant;
      FWbemObject   : OLEVariant;
      oEnum         : IEnumvariant;
      iValue        : LongWord;
    begin;
      FSWbemLocator := CreateOleObject('WbemScripting.SWbemLocator');
      FWMIService   := FSWbemLocator.ConnectServer('localhost', 'root\cimv2', '', '');
      FWbemObjectSet:= FWMIService.ExecQuery('SELECT * FROM  Win32_PnPEntity WHERE ConfigManagerErrorCode <> 0','WQL',wbemFlagForwardOnly);
      oEnum         := IUnknown(FWbemObjectSet._NewEnum) as IEnumVariant;
      while oEnum.Next(1, FWbemObject, iValue) = 0 do
      begin
        Writeln(Format('Class GUID %s',[String(FWbemObject.ClassGUID)]));
        Writeln(Format('Description %s',[String(FWbemObject.Description)]));
        Writeln(Format('Device ID %s',[String(FWbemObject.DeviceID)]));
        Writeln(Format('Manufacturer %s',[String(FWbemObject.Manufacturer)]));
        Writeln(Format('Name %s',[String(FWbemObject.Name)]));
        Writeln(Format('PNP Device ID %s',[String(FWbemObject.PNPDeviceID)]));
        Writeln('');
        FWbemObject:=Unassigned;
      end;
    end;

begin
 try
    CoInitialize(nil);
    try
      ListDevicesConfigError;
    finally
      CoUninitialize;
    end;
 except
    on E:EOleException do
        Writeln(Format('EOleException %s %x', [E.Message,E.ErrorCode])); 
    on E:Exception do
        Writeln(E.Classname, ':', E.Message);
 end;
 Writeln('Press Enter to exit');
 Readln;      
end.
```